# How to disable ascending/descending order in Banana Term Panel

Tags: solr, banana

In Banana, I can't visualize my Data (as a bar style) via a Term Panel without ascending order nor descending order.

Let's suppose that my field variable is a range time between 0 and 9 seconds and I want to show frequencies (option Mode=count) by keeping the normal range 0-9 onto my X axis. Then it's impossible ! I'm stuck to choose between 'ascending' order or descending' order, nothing else !

I tried to edit the file 'editor.html' to add a third option named 'normal' in addition to 'descending' and 'ascending', and I tried to edit the 'module.js' file to add new conditions (like: if $scope.panel.order === 'ascending', and if $scope.panel.order === 'normal' ), but nothing has changed...

Does anybody has a solution ? Thank you by advance.

Comment: Ok guys, I just solved the problem by using the new version of the Term Panel (the version of March 2016). In that version it's now possible to sort by 'index' in addition to sort by 'count'. I copied the Term component from Banana Github directly from the folder 'src/app/panels/terms'.

Comment: Let's notice that the new version of Term Panel associates the 'index' as a pure string label which will be sorted in ascending or descending. So for example if you use a range of integer indexes like [0:30] and you want to sort it in ascending, the Term Panel will sort them in the following way : [0,1,10:19,2,20:29,3,30,4:9]. That's a little bit stupid and sad, because this code could have been tested at minimum in a serious and professionnal way...